# OnClick #div1 change display to #div2

Tags: jquery, css

I have a `<div>` with a width and height of 200 pixels.
Inside that `<div>` there is a `display:none` image.

When I click the `<div>` I want the style of the image to become `display:block`. When I click it again to becomes `display:none` again.

Is that possible?

Comment: you should use jQuery click event

Comment: is it ok with jquery?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: please post some html also...

Comment: @mr.soroush unless it's obvious or the asker explicitly states that they are okay with using a certain tool (jQuery, in this case), please don't change the tags on questions. dominotrix hasn't hinted that using jQuery is okay, and tagging this with jQuery would completely change the answers received.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/36xDV/

Comment: @James Donnelly this question will solve with jquery easily. Maybe asker don't know this issue and retag help him.

Comment: @mr.soroush that's great, but when you originally tagged jQuery there was no hint that jQuery could be used. You should only add tags when you're sure that's what the asker is looking for.

Comment: Truth is, I didn't want jQuery unless it was the only option. I didn't wrote it not by mistake, but because I didn't want the answer to be an obvious jQuery related one. But thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If jQuery is ok, you can use:

CSS:

```
#img {display:none;}
```

jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#divID').click(function(){
        $('#img').toggle();
   });
}); 
</script>
```

Where #img is the id of your image. If you post more html we can answer more exact.

You just need to add the jQuery script library:
Add this in your page between the `<head>` tags:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it can be done done with css too

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/36xDV/

Comment: @dominotrix chek this http://jsfiddle.net/36xDV/1/  - Is this what you look for?

Comment: wait.. you just changed the settings on jsfiddle.. how can i make this work on my site? :S

Comment: @dominotrix, I will update my answer. You just need to load the jQuery library.

Comment: how.. and where? in the header.php? (it's a wordpress site).

Comment: @dominotrix, just updated my answer: Add this in your page between the `<head>` tags:

    `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I just did.. still not working. Checked the source code and the .js is correctly called. What could be wrong?

Comment: @dominotrix, check my answer again. I added $(document).ready(function(){, so that the code will only load when the page has loaded.

Comment: oh.. ok didnt update the code. Now its all good! Thanks again for your fast answers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on event **onclick** of div, just put the action, like this:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('image_id').style.display='block';"
```

If you want to change it, when is clicked again:

```
onclick="if(document.getElementById('image_id').style.display=='block'){document.getElementById('image_id').style.display=='none';}
else{document.getElementById('image_id').style.display='block';}"
```

Comment: The OP wants to toggle the display, so that isn't enough.

Comment: yes, I saw after, thanks

Comment: Hmm.. doesnt seem to work :/

Comment: The original styl of the image that is :none, should be inline styled? (<img src="..." style="display:none;" />) or inside a style.css ??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/36xDV/

Comment: yes, sorry, I'll be more specific. <div onclick="if(document.getElementById('image_id').style.display=='block') {document.getElementById('image_id').style.display='none';} else{document.getElementById('image_id').style.display='block';}"> <img id="image_id" style="display:none" src="img.jpg"> </div>

works for me